# calculate difference between two values after generalising a loop to display data in a table like on console

Tags: java

I have this code

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> entries = new HashMap<>();

List<String> innerMapKeys = new ArrayList<>();

innerMapKeys.add("key1");
innerMapKeys.add("key2");

System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("-", 38 * innerMapKeys.size()));

System.out.printf("|%10s|","");

for (String source : innerMapKeys) {

    System.out.printf("%30s|", StringUtils.center(source,31));
}

System.out.println();

System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("-", 38 * innerMapKeys.size()));

System.out.printf("|%10s|%15s|%15s|%15s|%15s|%10s|%10s|\n", "", "Sum", "Count", "Sum", "Count", "Diff Sum", "Diff Count");

System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("-", 38 * innerMapKeys.size()));

for (Map.Entry<String,Map<String,List<Integer>>> entry : entries.entrySet()) {

    System.out.printf("%15", entry.getKey());

    for (int i = 0; i < innerMapKeys.size(); i++) {

        if (i < innerMapKeys.size() - 1) {

            if(entry.getValue().contains(innerMapKeys.get(i))){

                List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get(innerMapKeys.get(i));

                for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {

                    System.out.printf("|%10d", values.get(j));

                }
            }
            else { 

                System.out.printf("|%20s", "MISSING"); 

            }
        }
        else {

            if(entry.getValue().contains(innerMapKeys.get(i))){

                List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get(innerMapKeys.get(i));

                for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {

                    System.out.printf("|%10d", values.get(j));

                }

                System.out.println("|");

            }
            else { 

                System.out.printf("|%20s|\n", "MISSING"); 

            }
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("-", 38 * innerMapKeys.size()));
```

which gives this output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          |    Data Source 1              |   Data Source 2               |          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          |            Sum|          Count|            Sum|          Count|  Diff Sum|Diff Count|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Key1|            479|            595|            479|            595|          |          |
|      Key2|            383|         13,452|            383|            452|          |          |
|      Key3|          7,969|         11,912|          7,969|          1,912|          |          |
|      Key4|         77,262|          3,478|         77,262|          3,478|          |          |
|      Key5|          2,333|          6,254|          2,333|          6,254|          |          |
|      Key6|            610|         89,636|            610|         89,636|          |          |
|      Key7|            541|         37,090|            541|         37,090|          |          |
|      Key8|            994|         80,472|            994|         80,472|          |          |
|      Key9|         14,214|          5,078|         14,214|          5,078|          |          |
|     Key10|            587|         64,840|            587|         64,840|          |          |
|     Key11|            153|         61,769|            643|         61,730|          |          |
|     Key12|            400|          5,635|            400|          5,635|          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to fill out columns `Diff Sum` and `Diff Count`, where there are the difference between the `Sum` columns and `Count` columns respectively.

Originally, my `for` loop looked like

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Map<String,List<Integer>>> entry : entries.entrySet()) {

    System.out.printf("%15", entry.getKey());

    if(entry.getValue().contains("key1")){
        List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get("key1");
        System.out.printf("%10d%10d", values.get(0), values.get(1));
    }else { 

        System.out.printf("%20s", "MISSING"); 

    }

    if (entry.getValue().containsKey("key2")) { 

        List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get("key2"); 

        System.out.printf("%10d%10d", values.get(0), values.get(1)); 

    } else { 

        System.out.printf("%20d\n", "MISSING"); 

    }

    if(entry.getValue().contains("key1") && entry.getValue().contains("key2")){
        System.out.printf("%10d%10d\n", Math.abs(entry.getValue().get("key1").get(0) - entry.getValue().get("key2").get(0)),
                            Math.abs(entry.getValue().get("key1").get(1) - entry.getValue().get("key2").get(1)));
    }
}
```

which was also filling out the columns mentioned above. It was after I generalised that I could not find a way to fill those columns.
Any suggestions on how I could go about that?

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you have a method to calculate everything first, then a method to print it.  These are very different separation of concerns and should not be combined.

Also have a map of maps can get confusing, I would suggest you create a container Java class and have SumFromData1, CountFromData1, SumFromData2, CountFromData2, getDifferenceSum, getDiffCount which can just be getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way a few days ego on how I can do that. By adding another `for` loop, after that inner loop, I managed to get the result I wanted. I am still hoping to found a way to optimize the whole loop. Anyways, my loop became this one:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Map<String,List<Integer>>> entry : entries.entrySet()) {

    System.out.printf("%15", entry.getKey());

    for (int i = 0; i < innerMapKeys.size(); i++) {

        if (i < innerMapKeys.size() - 1) {

            if(entry.getValue().contains(innerMapKeys.get(i))){

                List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get(innerMapKeys.get(i));

                for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {

                    System.out.printf("|%10d", values.get(j));

                }
            }
            else { 

                System.out.printf("|%20s", "MISSING"); 

            }
        }
        else {

            if(entry.getValue().contains(innerMapKeys.get(i))){

                List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get(innerMapKeys.get(i));

                for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {

                    System.out.printf("|%10d", values.get(j));

                }

                System.out.println("|");

            }
            else { 

                System.out.printf("|%20s", "MISSING"); 

            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size()-1;++i){ // keys is a set of String that contains all the keys of my outer map

        if(entry.getValue().contains(innerMapKeys.get(i))){

            List<Integer> values = entry.getValue().get(innerMapKeys.get(i));


            System.out.printf("%10d%10d\n",
                Math.abs(entry.getValue().get(i).get(0) - entry.getValue().get(i+1).get(0)),
                Math.abs(entry.getValue().get(i).get(1) - entry.getValue().get(i+1).get(1)))

        }
        else { 

            System.out.printf("|%20s|\n", "MISSING"); 

        }
    }
}
```